# Activity tab shows that I have approved my own edit suggestion

Tags: bug, status-norepro, suggested-edits, recent-activity

The [activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287954/?tab=activity) says I have voted to approve edits suggested by myself:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real problem is that both the "suggestions" and "reviews" tabs use the same tooltip; this means that, when viewing the activity as shown in the "all" tab is not possible to understand if the activity is referring to a review the user has done, or a suggestion the user has done.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

When the entry is about a suggestion, the tooltip should be "the suggested edit has been approved," when it has been approved, or "the suggested edit has been rejected"; in this way, when looking the list of all the activities, it would be possible to understand when the entry is about a review done by the user, or a suggested edit.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like these tooltips are just gone now, so I'm resolving this.